# Subquery returned more than 1 value. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure and can't execute it because I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression."

This is part of the stored procedure where the problem occurs. I am using this piece of code inside a CURSOR, which (as long as I understand it correctly) works record by record. With that in mind. I don't see the problem.

```
SELECT @Public_amount = (SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN cl.[Tram_periodicity] = '1' THEN pca.[5day] -- of 6 dagen, who knows?
    WHEN cl.[Tram_periodicity] = '2' THEN pca.Monthly
        -- According to Marina, trimestriële is never used. This is code '3'
    WHEN cl.[Tram_periodicity] = '4' THEN pca.Yearly
    WHEN cl.[Tram_periodicity] = '5' THEN pca.Railflex
    ELSE NULL
    END
    FROM [TC].[TC_Control_List] AS cl
    LEFT JOIN [TC].[PC_amount] AS pca
    ON cl.CPARC = pca.PC
    WHERE (CAST(@TRAM_DISTANCE AS NUMERIC)>=pca.[FROM] AND CAST(@TRAM_DISTANCE AS NUMERIC)<=pca.till)
    AND pca.Type = 'Public' AND pca.PC = '20000')
```

Comment: That SQL isn't complete; that parenthesis is never closed. On the subject of your error, however, what is it you don't understand? The error is one of the (far) more clear errors from SQL Server. but, to state the obvious, your subquery is returning more than one row and it follows the `=` operator. As it follows the `=` operator the subquery can only return 1 or 0 rows. Without, however, knowing your required behaviour we can't specifically help you further.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I don't know how that could be more clear. You are setting a variable to the result of a query. Obviously that query returns more than 1 row so you get that error message. Run that query by itself and you will see it returns at least 2 rows.

Comment: The cursor might work row by row but how are you identifying a single row here? Seems like maybe you forgot to include a key column in the where clause...

Comment: The lack of closing parenthesis is my fault, I forgot to copy it along.
The subquery is based on data from the one single row the cursor works with. So I'm thinking that the subquery would also return just one row. Am I correct to assume it that way?

Comment: So the sub-query returns more than 1 row.  Hence the error. But which of those should be assigned to @Public_amount ? SUM the CASE WHEN? MAX the CASE WHEN ? A TOP 1 based on an ORDER BY?   Choices, choices...

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using a `CURSOR`? From experience, they are almost always misused. Perhaps the better question here would be "How can I change this iterative process into a dataset process?"

Comment: @HoneyBadger no, it won't. That query will most definately cause that error. Try `DECLARE @i int = (SELECT i FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) V(i));` You're thinking of the syntax `DECLARE @i int; SELECT @i = i FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) V(i);`, which would set the value of `@i` to the last value returned.

Comment: @Larnu, Yeah, you're right, I missed the inner select. I had something like `DECLARE @Val INT 
SELECT  @Val = V.i
FROM  (VALUES(1),(2)) V(i)
` in mind

Comment: "based on the data from one single row" how? All you've done is a range query against `@TRAM_DISTANCE`. Is `@TRAM_DISTANCE` a key that yields exactly one row? Obviously not (or you wouldn't be getting the error message).

Comment: *"I am using this piece of code inside a CURSOR, which (as long as I understand it correctly) works record by record."* yes, and no. Yes, it works row by row, but if you want the behaviour you are expecting, then each value needs to be **unique**. I suspect you have behaviour very similar to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e062a691a70f58a056daf0920553493), and hence why you're getting the error. As I commented earlier though, I doubt you even need a cursor and very likely you could write a (more efficient) dataset solution.

Comment: I am using a cursor because I am editing some work of an ex-coworker. I thought it would be less work to just edit it. Also note that I am working with rather small amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is clearly saying that your `subquery` return more than one records, you need either `top (1)` clause or use table variable instead to stored all rows in table :

```
SELECT TOP (1) @Public_amount = CASE WHEN cl.[Tram_periodicity] = '1' THEN pca.[5day] -- of 6 dagen, who knows?
                                     WHEN cl.[Tram_periodicity] = '2' THEN pca.Monthly -- According to Marina, trimestriële is never used. This is code '3'
                                     WHEN cl.[Tram_periodicity] = '4' THEN pca.Yearly
                                     WHEN cl.[Tram_periodicity] = '5' THEN pca.Railflex
                                END
 . . .
```

However, this might be not resolve your actual problem but yes it resolve your compilation error.

Comment: Just note that `TOP (1)` will give you an arbitrary row and it won't necessarily be the one you want. Also, the `TOP (1)` needs to be inside the subquery (putting it outside without otherwise changing the OP's code leads to the same error).

Comment: `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` is not going to give reliable behaviour.

Comment: @Larnu. . .  The statement is not complete, it just reflects the actual problem. BTW, agreed on `TOP 1 without an ORDER BY`.